# How to update table row in Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I have a score table with an array of players added in my initial constructor like so:

```
for( int i=0; i<this.players.size; i++ ) {
    scoreTable.add( new Label(players.get(i).getName(), skin) ); // first column
    scoreTable.add( new Label(players.get(i).getScore() + "", skin) ); // second column
    scoreTable.row();
}

+----------+--------+
| Player A |    0   |
+----------+--------+
| Player B |    0   |
+----------+--------+
| Player C |    0   |
+----------+--------+
```

Now in my render() method, I want to update the player score in the table but I have no idea how to get the referencing index to be able to do so. Any ideas would be appreciated as I can't seems to find any example on the net or doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick way would be to call `scoreTable.getChildren()` which will return you an SnapshotArray object that holds all child actors of the table.

So if you want to get the first item you could get it like this: `scoreTable.getChildren().get(0);` etc.

Comment: Thanks! Getting close but how to get the score column? Currently it is getting Name column.

Comment: Is it? I was rather expecting that the even index numbers like (0,2,4..) will be the labels of the first columns while the odd numbers are the 2nd column (1,3,5..)

Comment: Yes I think you are right because my table consist of a title label as well, so this makes it the first column with odd numbers and the score column with even. Kinda tricky, hence i just use .getChildren().get(n*2) to get to the 2nd column. Thank you so much don, you saved my sleep!